# Spring Boot JPA: Passing Multiple Values for the Same Parameter (JPQL)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I'm using JPQL to write SQL queries in JPA's `CurdRepository` interface. I was able to write more than one query with named parameters and they work like a charm.

However, my application requires that I match an unknown number of strings with more than one column in a table. To my knowledge, in SQL it'd look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_1 LIKE "%string_1%" OR COLUMN_1 LIKE"%string_2%" ... OR COLUMN_2 LIKE "%string_1%" OR COLUMN_2 LIKE "%string_2%" ... ...
```

I tried this in MySQL and it works fine. I couldn't figure out how to depict this in JPQL, however. I was able to pass multiple values for the `IN` clause by setting the named parameter to a `List`, as follows:

```
 @Query("SELECT t FROM Table t WHERE TABLE_ID IN (:table_ids)")
public Page<Table> findByParameters(@Param("table_ids") List<Integer> table_ids, Pageable page)
```

I tried doing the same thing with the `LIKE` clause but I end up with 0 results if I pass more than 1 value. I face the same problem with the `LOCATE` clause as well.

Worst case scenario, I can set up one query that works on one String, and call it several times and then merge all the results. I'd very much rather avoid this however, as it'd be nothing more than a duct-tape solution.

I looked online for solutions for hours but haven't found anything that addresses my concern. Any tip is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you access the `EntityManager` used by your spring repository? I mean, do you have a Service where you can inject the `EntityManager` ?

Comment: @CarlitosWay I do have a service but I'm not using `EntityManager`. I have a repository interface that implements `CrudRepository`, and using the service I invoke the different methods from said repository.

Comment: @CarlitosWay I am using entity manager Is there an easy hack using entity manager

Comment: @MohitArora, I've implemented this type of requirement by creating a dynamic JQPL string query based on the supplied filters/arguments and configuring it based on such arguments ... eventually, you end invoking [createQuery(theDynamicQuery, EntityClass)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) and executing such query object ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `@Query` needs to be fixed at compile time using JPQL or even native query will make this kind of things hard to implement especially in a type safe way.

So I realize you are after JPQL solution but this is an awesome opportunity to learn and take advantage of `Specification` interface and JPA's CriteriaQuery. This is exactly it is for.

Take a look at the following repository:

```
public interface Table1Repository            // to use specifications in queries 
        extends JpaRepository<Table1, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Table1> {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static Specification<Table1> multiLikeColumn1(List<String> likePatterns) {
        return new Specification<Table1>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Table1> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Path<String> column1 = root.get("column1");
                // create a Predicate for each "column1 like 'xy%az%' you need
                List<Predicate> predicates = likePatterns.stream()
                    .map(likePattern -> criteriaBuilder.like(column1, likePattern))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                // then "concatenate" list of likes with "OR"
                return criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
            }
        };
    }

}
```

It might look a bit complex but actually it is not when you get familiar with it. Usage is simple, like:

```
@Resource
private Table1Repository repo;
repo.findAll(Table1Repository.multiLikeColumn1(Arrays.asList("%X%","%Z%")))
```

Comment: Even better, the following can be done to return paged results:
`repo.findAll(Table1Repository.multiLikeColumn1(Arrays.asList("%X%","%Z%")),new PageRequest(pagenum, page_offset))`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1)

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Post> {
```

2. ```
   public class PostSpecification {
         public static Specification<Post> textContains(String searchWord) {
             return (root, query, builder) -> {
                 Expression<String> searchLowerCase = builder.lower(root.get("text"));
                 return builder.like(searchLowerCase, "%" + searchWord.toLowerCase() + "%");
             };
         }
     }
   ```
3. 

```
public Page<Post> getPostsWhereTextContainsAnyWord(List<String> words, int offset, int limit) {
        Specification<Post> specification = null;
        for(String word : words) {
            Specification<Post> wordSpecification = PostSpecification.textContains(word);
            if(specification == null) {
                specification = wordSpecification;
            } else {
                specification = specification.or(wordSpecification);
            }
        }
        return postRepository.findAll(specification, PageRequest.of(offset, limit));
    }
```